# Unrecognized locale base.lproj while uploading app in ios store

Tags: ios, cordova

> Unrecognized Locale - The directory located at (
>   'Payload/FioriClientApp.app/MAFLogonCoreCDVPlugin.bundle/base.lproj',
>   'Payload/FioriClientApp.app/SMPAuthProxyPlugin.bundle/base.lproj',
>   'Payload/FioriClientApp.app/SMPToolbarPlugin.bundle/base.lproj',
>   'Payload/FioriClientApp.app/Settings.bundle/base.lproj' ) has an
>   unrecognized locale name. Refer to the Language and Locale
>   Designations guide for more information on naming your
>   language-specific directories.

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?